# String concatenation - preg_match() expects string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, string-concatenation

```
public function getDownload($name){
    $file = storage_path().'/cv/'.$name; //error here
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Description'       => 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Type'              => 'application/pdf',
    );
    return Response::download($file, $headers);
}
```

I just want to concatenate all in one variable. All parameters are string.
Below is one var_dump () of the two variavaies storage_path() and $name.

[image]

Comment: Wherever your error comes from: maybe it complains about `$headers`, not about `$file`?

Comment: It is true @DerVO. Ty. 
return Response::download($file, null, $headers);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to take a look at the download method of the Request factory you will find that you are missing a parameter.

```
public function download($file, $name = null, array $headers = array(), $disposition = 'attachment');
```